# I have to use a jQuery mouse scroll animation effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

Please check this link http://test.hybreed.co/demo2/
    Its working without mouse scroll but i want to use this mouse scroll animation. If any user hit the link on URL, letter space should be 50px.If first mouse scroll happen than letter space should be 35px, If second mouse scroll happen than letter should be 15px.Please help me with jquery code .

**HTML**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="header-text">
        <ul>

            <li><h2 class="letter-1">A</h2></li>
            <li><h2 >B</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="letter-3">C</h2></li>

            <li><h2 class="letter-1">D</h2></li>
            <li><h2>E</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="letter-3">F</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="letter-7">G</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="letter-8">H</h2></li>


            <li><h2 class="letter-1">I</h2></li>
            <li><h2>J</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="letter-3">K</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="letter-4">L</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="letter-5">M</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="letter-6">N</h2></li>
    </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**css**

```
    .header-text
    {

        text-align: center;
    }

    ul li{

        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;

    }

    ul li h2{

        float: left;
        letter-spacing: 50px;

        margin:300px 12px;
        }


        .letter-1{
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: move-h 5s forwards;
            animation: move-h  5s forwards;

        }


        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes move-h  {
        from {left: 0px;}
        to {left: 50px; text-align: center;}
    }

    @keyframes move-h  {
        from {left: 0px;}
        to {left: 50px; text-align: center;}

    }





    .letter-3{
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: letter-3-e 5s forwards;
            animation: letter-3-e  5s forwards;
        }


        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes letter-3-e   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 50px;text-align: center;}
    }

    @keyframes letter-3-e   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 50px;text-align: center;}
    }


    .letter-4
    {position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: letter-4-d 5s forwards;
        animation: letter-4-d  5s forwards;
        }



        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes letter-4-d   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 100px;}
    }

    @keyframes letter-4-d   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 100px;}
    }




    .letter-5
    {position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: letter-5-i 5s forwards;
        animation: letter-5-i  5s forwards;
        }



        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes letter-5-i   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 150px;}
    }

    @keyframes letter-5-i   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 150px;}
    }


    .letter-6
    {position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: letter-6-o 5s forwards;
        animation: letter-6-o  5s forwards;
        }



        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes letter-6-o   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 200px;}
    }

    @keyframes letter-6-o   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 200px;}
    }



    .letter-7
    {

        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: letter-7-o 5s forwards;
        animation: letter-7-o  5s forwards;
        }


        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes letter-7-o   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 100px;}
    }

    @keyframes letter-7-o   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 100px;}
    }

    .letter-8

    {

        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation: letter-8-n 5s forwards;
        animation: letter-8-n  5s forwards;
        }



        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes letter-8-n   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 150px;}
    }

    @keyframes letter-8-n   {
        from {right: 0px;}
        to {right: 150px; }
    }


    .header-text-center
    {


    }

      [1]: http://test.hybreed.co/demo2/
```

Comment: Hi @Hybreeder if possible as scroll size as e. 50px .. and the 100px it I do ... but can't get first scroll, second scroll ... if do as "PX" let me info i will help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Mansukh . Ok.Please help  me with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check it may be helps.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(e) {
  
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50 && jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 300){
   jQuery('.effect-spase').css({'letter-spacing':35});
  }
  else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 300){
   jQuery('.effect-spase').css({'letter-spacing':15});
  }
  else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 50){   
   jQuery('.effect-spase').css({'letter-spacing':50});
  }
    });
});
```

```css
.header-text
{
 
    height: 1000px;
    text-align: center;    
    width: 100%;
}

.effect-spase{
 position:fixed;
 font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 50px;
    
 
 transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;

 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-text">
 <div class="effect-spase">Mansukh</div>
</div>
```

Comment: info me it's help or not

Comment: i approved his answer @Mansukh Khandhar here is an jsfiddle working with code https://jsfiddle.net/jssdf3uz/

Comment: Mr.Mansukh. can you help  me one more help   after completed the animate can we display the text in center?

Comment: check mt second answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(e) {
  
       if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50 && jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 300){
   
    
   jQuery('.effect-spase').css({'letter-spacing':35,'left':'auto'});
  }
  else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 300){
    
   jQuery('.effect-spase').css({'letter-spacing':15,'left':'41%'});
  }
  else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 50){   
   
   jQuery('.effect-spase').css({'letter-spacing':50,'left':'auto'});
  }
    });
});
```

```css
.header-text
{
 
    height: 1000px;
    text-align: center;    
    width: 100%;
}

.effect-spase{
 position:fixed;
 font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 50px;
    
 
 transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;

 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-text">
 <div class="effect-spase">Mansukh</div>
</div>
```